# How do I write to an AWS DynamoDB table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, processing

When I try to write a variable to a DynamoDB 2.0 Table in Processing (Java mode), I get the following error:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

The piece of code I've written for this is the following:

```java
DataTable.updateItem("PrimaryKey", "2" , "Score", newNumber);
```

`DataTable` is the table, `PrimaryKey` is the name of the primary key, `2` is the value I want for the primary key, `"Score"` is the name of the Item value I want to modify, and `newNumber` is the value I want to give it.

What structure do I need to use in the `updateItem` function? After looking at online examples and such, I've tried a few different structures and tried using for example a `PrimaryKey` variable (which it didn't seem to accept), but I can't get it to work. Reading from the table works perfectly, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `updateItem` method has several overloads. I assume you are attempting to use this one: `updateItem(String tableName, Map<String,AttributeValue> key, Map<String,AttributeValueUpdate> attributeUpdates)`.

Try something like this instead:

```java
dynamodbClient.updateItem(
    "DataTable", 
    Map.of("PrimaryKey", new AttributeValue("2"),
    Map.of("Score", new AttributeValue().withN(newNumber),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried that, but I get the following error: ```The function "of(String,AttributeValue)" does not exist```. After reading the Java documentation a bit, it looks like maybe the `Map.of()` function is new to Java 9? And apparently Processing currently uses java 8.

Comment: You can still do it without the `Map.of()` function, that's just shorthand. You can create a `Map<string, AttributeValue>` variable and `.add("PrimaryKey", new AttributeValue("2)` to it. Then pass the variable (one for each parameter) to the method.

Comment: I've tried researching it as much as I can, but still can't get it working... Here's my code: `Map<String, AttributeValue> dbKey;
  dbKey.put("PrimaryKey", new AttributeValue("2"));
  Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeUpdates;
  attributeUpdates.put("Score", new AttributeValue().withN(newScore));
  try {
    dynamoDB.updateItem(
     "Mathtermind",
     dbKey, 
     attributeUpdates
     );` But I get the following error: `The function "updateItem(String,String,AttributeValue>,String,AttributeValue>)" does not exist`. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong... Thanks!